# Visual Studio extension: hook on move file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-extensions, solution-explorer

I'm sure everyone who has been working with TFS at some point was annoyed by the fact that you will lose file history when moving files in **between projects** using the solution explorer (files will be deleted and added, not moved).

So I was searching quite a lot what kind of solutions there are. The "best" solution was to do it in SourceControlExplorer.

I still find this very annoying, so I was thinking about writing an extension which hooks on the moving on a file within the solution explorer and perform the respective TFS move action. I have never seen an extension doing something similar like that and also could not find some.

Can someone with some extension programming experience if this is something an extension is capable of? Can I intercept default behavior and execute my own?

Hope this is not an of topic question!?

Comment: So there already is a hook is used by TFS to handle file moves within a project. To confirm, the problem you're seeing is if you move files _between_ projects?

Comment: Correct, moving files whithin the same project is no problem. I somehow forgot to state that explicitly, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to develop an app for the TFS. There are differen use cases for developing application around the TFS. This sounds like a use case for the server. Your application extends the file management system on the server.

if you meant something completely different i'm sorry.

if you really want to do it in Visual Studio, you can develop an extension that extends the SourceControlExplorer. It is possible to get the complete history of a file and to modify the history itself.

Comment: I think the problem when doing it on TFS is, that you somehow need to know which file has been deleted and where was it added. This is especially a problem when renaming the file after moving it within the same shelfset. So I don't think a server-side solution will help here. Same think counts for modifing the history I think